# How might I create a Typed Configuration Map similar to SBT's new configuration?

Tags: scala

I am new to Scala and still wrapping my head around the type system and how flexible it is / is not. I'm having some issues understanding some of the type scoping and what type parameters I can and cannot refer to when defining parameters in various locations - especially with "higher kinded types" where I'm nesting types at two levels, ie: `Foo[T <: Bar[U]](x: U) // U does not seem to be accessible here as a type for x`

What I'd like to be able to do is define a Config type which is typesafe but generic enough to be used for multiple types (`Config[T]`), such that I can pass in `Config[T](c: Map[AttributeKey[Attribute[T]], AttributeValue[Attribute[T]]])` which enforces that only `AttributeKey`s for `T` can be passed in, and, similarly, only `AttributeValue`s fora specific `Attribute` for `T`.

What I have defined below does not work, and I have a feeling I may be going down the wrong path. I would really love if someone could help me detangle it and understand it a bit more. I've tried taking a look at the SBT source, but haven't been able to distill it down to the parts that I need.

```scala
package foo.conf

package object conf {

  case object Provider {
    sealed trait Type {
      def name: String
      override def toString = name
    }

    sealed trait MyProvider extends Type {
      val name = "MyProvider"
    }
  }

  import Provider._

  case class Provider[T <: Type](config: Config[T])

  case object Config {

    sealed trait Attribute[T <: Type, VT] {
      def name: String
      def value: VT
      override def toString = name
    }

    final case class AttributeKey[T <: Attribute](name: String)
    case object AttributeKey {
      implicit def attributeToKey[T <: Attribute](a: T): AttributeKey[T] = AttributeKey(a.name)
    }


    final case class AttributeValue[VT, T: Attribute[_, VT]](value: VT)
    case object AttributeValue {
      implicit def attributeToValue[T](a: Attribute[_, T]): AttributeValue[T] = AttributeValue(a.value)
    }


    case class MyProviderSpecificAttr[T: String](value: T) extends Attribute[MyProvider, T] {
      val name = "my-provider-specific-attr"
    }

    case object `my-provider-specific-attr-val-1` extends MyProviderSpecificAttr("my-provider-specific-attr-val-1")
    case object `my-provider-specific-attr-val-2` extends MyProviderSpecificAttr("my-provider-specific-attr-val-2")
  }

  import Config._
  final case class Config[T <: Type](c: Map[AttributeKey[Attribute[T, _]], AttributeValue])

  val test = Config[MyProvider](Map(
    MyProviderSpecificAttr -> `my-provider-specific-attr-val-1`
  ))



}
```

Comment: `Foo[T <: Bar[U]](x: U) // U does not seem to be accessible here as a type for x` - I've also run into this recently, +1.